# Rewrite rule to load images from production does nothing

Tags: url-rewriting, uploads, htaccess, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to adapt the rewrite rule given in [Develop Locally, Use Images from Production](https://css-tricks.com/develop-locally-use-images-production/) to do the very same thing on my local dev site (which runs on XAMPP).

This is how the development site's `.htaccess` looks, with the snippet added towards the end of it (URL replaced with example.com equivalent, obviously):

```
<IfModule mod_php.c>
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
</IfModule>

#START WORDPRESS

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/

# Redirect About and Library to first sub page 
RewriteRule ^about/?$ /wordpress/about/history/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^the-library/?$ /wordpress/the-library/gallery/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# If images not found on development site, load from production 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/uploads/[^\/]*/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

#END WORDPRESS
```

The rewrite rule doesn't seem to be making a difference, whether with the HTTPS or HTTP version of the URL. Images unavailable for the dev site simply don't display, even when the same images load fine for the production site.

I also had no luck trying to adapt the rewrite rule found in this [slightly different question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/299097/167562) applying to Wordpress Multisite.

Additionally, I previously added a filter to [stop Wordpress from modifying the .htaccess file](https://perishablepress.com/stop-wordpress-htaccess/), so am pretty sure that this isn't the cause of the problem.

What is wrong with my rewrite rule here that's causing it to fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . index.php [L]
>
> # If images not found on development site, load from production 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/uploads/[^\/]*/.*$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

The problem here is that "If images not found on development site" then the request has already been rewritten to `index.php` by the preceding `RewriteRule` (WordPress front-controller), so your rule block that follows does nothing.

NB: Whilst you've not explicitly included the `R` (`redirect`) flag on the `RewriteRule`, this will implicitly trigger an external 302 (temporary) redirect, the same as if you had explicitly included `R=302` on the directive. Explicitly including this flag is preferable to more clearly communicate its intent. In fact, you might want to change this to a 301 so that images are cached, thus preventing external redirects to your production server on every request.

The `QSA` flag is not required here, since you are not including a query string on the `RewriteRule` *susbstitution*.

*Aside:* Your `RewriteRule` arguably matches too match... it matches *everything*, not just images, is that intentional?

You could resolve this by either...

1. preventing *all* image URLs being processed by the front-controller. For example, add an additional condition to the WP front-controller to exclude images:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]
   ```
2. OR, move your redirect to *above* the WP front-controller, and check for the non-existence of the requested file before redirecting to your production server. I would also be more restrictive on the regex and match only images (as mentioned above) - if that is the intention. For example:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

   # If images not found on development site, load from production
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/[^/]+/.+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ https://www.example.com/$0 [R=302,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]
   ```

The additional condition is not required, as you can perform the URL comparison in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (more efficient). The slash does not need to be escaped in the character class (or anywhere for that matter). And the `QSA` flag is not required here (as mentioned above).

Note that the regex matches URL-paths of the form `/wp-content/uploads/<somedirectory>/<something>.jpg`, where `<something>` can be any number of additional subdirectories. This is based on your regex.

The `$0` backreference (as opposed to `$1` in your original directive) is the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. `$1` contains the first captured subgroup. In the revised directive, the first captured subgroup contains just the image file extension.

Comment: Definitely not intentional, the last two rewrite rules are those copy-pasted from CSS Tricks, and everything above is what existed in my .htaccess prior, so it's highly possible there's some overlap and inefficiencies.

Comment: Thank you for a well-written and comprehensive answer, it's refreshing to read about how this stuff actually works rather than just have the solutions given, especially when it's as complex a beast as Apache directives are. I opted for the second solution and now it works perfectly. Also, thanks for the reference to the Wordpress "front-end controller", I had always wondered what those default rules actually did and how they worked, but didn't know there was a term for them. I'm now reading [this](https://wpshout.com/wordpress-front-controller/).